# Magento 2.3 - Add order attribute

Tags: magento2.3, orders, custom-attributes

I need to add a text attribute to placed orders, filled by logic in a observer module. Now I used/follow [this code](https://github.com/yereone/NewOrderAttribute) before on Magento **2.2** and there it worked like expected. Now, copying the same module to Magento **2.3** doesn't seem to fire the `installData` at all (I added logging to check, never comes up in the logs), so the required database columns aren't created, thus my order-process is now broken.

Now I've seen and [read this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html) about declarative schema, that the `installData` is being phased out, but I also understand that it should still work in 2.3, and I haven't the time to rewrite the module.

My `installData` contents are now this (this is the code that worked in 2.2 but not 2.3)

```
<?php
namespace DC\OrderAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory
     */
    protected $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) 
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'sales_setup', 'setup' => $installer]);

        $salesSetup->addAttribute(Order::ENTITY, 'dc_order', [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length'=> 255,
            'visible' => false,
            'nullable' => true
        ]);

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('sales_order_grid'),
            'dc_order',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'comment' =>'Order to dc'
            ]
        );

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me figure out why these tables aren't created?
I've uninstalled/removed the module and the corresponding row in `setup_module` in the database to trigger the install each time; no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine: I have run it on Magento 2.3.3 and the attributes are created correctly.
My guess is your module is installed into your system and therefore you'd need to add the sql into an **UpgradeData script** for instance?

to see whether your module is part of your Magento 2.3.3 system, you may go to your setup_module: `select * from setup_module where module='DC_OrderAttributes';

More simply, `php bin/magento module:status` should list your module

To remove your module, you can physically delete from setup_module the row mentioning your module. (please backup your system if this is the option you choose). Then flush your cache to reinstall the module

The most recommended way is to use the UpgradeData rather than InstallData

Comment: Right.. This is good news in some way. But I don't understand why it won't work on my install then; I deleted the row from `setup_module`, disabled the mod via CLI, ran all the setup/compile commands etc multiple times and it just won't fire.. I'll try it with `UpgradeData` then, see what happens.. Thanks so far!

Comment: of course, setting up x-debug will go a long way for you not to have to guess the issue

Comment: Sure, but I've spent way more hours trying to setup x-debug and not able to get it working either :P

Comment: Well completely removed the module again, added the update data script, still nothing. I'm losing my mind I think.

Comment: try php bin/magento cac:cle, php bin/magento set:upg and if nothing, check browser console error, server logs.. It can be a nasty hunt but ultimately, it seems your system has an error somewhere

Comment: Of course I cleared all the caches, indexes and everything. I'm no expert, but no noob either ;)

Comment: go back to basics, disable all custom modules. Run php bin/magento set:upg to verify the module installs.. and gradually enable your modules one by one.. to find the culprit

Comment: Well screw me silly; I just added all the `installData` into another module along with some other attributes to setup and that one does fire like expected :/

Comment: I have some ideas to check your xdebug config, pm me your details and I will send you 2 pics showing my computer config that I had just to tune today..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101277/discussion-between-alex-timmer-and-herve-tribouilloy).